# Installing react-redux-firebase package with React 18

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I'm trying to install this package `npm install --save react-redux-firebase`  for React and I'm getting this error `“Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-side-effect@2.1.1”` I use 18.2 version of React

```
  npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: professional-resources@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-redux-firebase@3.11.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react-redux-firebase
    npm ERR!   react-redux-firebase@"*" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resoluti
```

on.

What can i do:

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this library does not support react 18 or if they support it they didn't add it as a peer deps: [see](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/9041285810f5650068967de2493b9cbe9f994cac/package.json#L65)

You have multiple solutions:

- Downgrading to react 17
- Asking library maintainers and help them to upgrade to react 18
- Forcing versions with [npm resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) (Use it at your own risk as the library does not support react 18 inside their peerDeps)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps react-redux-firebase redux-firestore
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.